# Dialogflow webhook fulfillment parameter not accessible

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, google-api-nodejs-client

I want to get input of a parameter in my webhook fulfillment.

Here is the my code:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var request = require('request-promise-native');
const { dialogflow } = require('actions-on-google');
const assistant = dialogflow({
  clientId: "30xxxxx08407-rv9kxxxxxxxxuuq8f9ul2eg.apps.googleusercontent.com"
});


module.exports = (app) => {
  const logger = console;

assistant.intent('Sales', conv => {
 const pcode = agent.parameters['PCODE'];
 console.log(pcode)

    const token = '3369708919812376';
    const serviceID = '502';
    const P_STATE_CD = 'ALL';
    const P_FO_CD = 'ALL';
    const P_DISTT_CD = 'ALL';
    const P_DATE = '16/12/2019';
    const P_PRD_GROUP = 'UREA';
    const P_PERSONAL_NO = '106296';

        var data = {"token" : token,"serviceID" : serviceID,"P_STATE_CD" : P_STATE_CD,"P_FO_CD" : P_FO_CD,"P_DISTT_CD" : P_DISTT_CD,"P_DATE" : P_DATE,"P_PRD_GROUP" : P_PRD_GROUP,"P_PERSONAL_NO" : P_PERSONAL_NO };
        var sdata = JSON.stringify(data);

                    const options = {
                        method: 'POST',
                        uri: 'http://Webservice/resources/webservice/service' ,
                        body: JSON.parse(sdata) ,
                        json: true
                    }
        return request(options)
            .then( body => {
                 var unit = body
                 console.log(body)
                 unit.intent = "Sales"
                 unit.value1 = unit.saleInfo[0].QMTD
                 unit.value2 = unit.saleInfo[0].QYTD
                 unit.value3 = unit.saleInfo[0].O_UOM
                 unit.value4 = null
                 unit.value5 = null

                 delete unit.saleInfo
                 var unit2 = JSON.stringify(unit)
                console.log(unit2)
          conv.ask(unit2);
              })
              .catch( err => {
               console.error( err );
               conv.ask('Something went wrong. What should I do now?');
                 });
  })
```

I tried with `const pcode = agent.parameters.PCODE` but it is not working. Giving me error:

> ReferenceError: agent is not defined
>       at assistant.intent.conv (/home/dbalounge/GoogleDF/service.js:15:16)
>       at Function. (/home/dbalounge/GoogleDF/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:151:27)
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at /home/dbalounge/GoogleDF/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:22:71
>       at new Promise ()
>       at __awaiter (/home/dbalounge/GoogleDF/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:18:12)
>       at Function.handler (/home/dbalounge/GoogleDF/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:85:16)
>       at Object. (/home/dbalounge/GoogleDF/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/assistant.js:55:32)
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at /home/dbalounge/GoogleDF/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/assistant.js:22:71

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`agent` is not defined anywhere in your code, that's why you're getting:

```
ReferenceError: agent is not defined
```

In any case if you use `assistant.parameters` won't work either. Dialogflow intent parameters can be accessed through the second argument of `.intent` callback.

```
assistant.intent('Sales', (conv, params) => {
     const pcode = params.PCODE;
     /* ... */
})
```

For more info you can check the [docs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actions/reference/nodejsv2/overview#access_parameters_and_contexts)

Comment: Hello Sir,  Its working but when i am trying put parameter in apis         var data = {"token" : pcode};
        var sdata = JSON.stringify(data);

                    const options = {
                        method: 'POST',
                        uri: 'http://Webservice/resources/webservice/service' ,
                        body: JSON.parse(sdata) ,
                        json: true
                    } than its giving error like this _TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined_.  @marcos casagrande

Comment: Please create a new question with your new issue, and I'll be happy to help you. Post the link here and I'll check it out

Comment: Hello, here is the link please help me out on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59446872/dialogflow-webhook-fulfillment-parameter-is-not-working-in-post-api) @marcos

Comment: Sorry, But believe me that is by mistake...I appreciate your work...thank your your valuable reply  @marcos