# Dialogflow webhook fulfillment parameter is not working in post API

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I make a code in webhook were i want invoke POST API and i want to invoke that api for that i have to pass some parameter but whenever i am trying to pass parameter coming from dialogflow its gives error. My code is like that

```
//Self Hosted Express Server

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var request = require('request-promise-native');
const { dialogflow } = require('actions-on-google');
const assistant = dialogflow({
  clientId: "305xxxxxx7-rv9kocdq2xxxxouuq8f9ul2eg.apps.googleusercontent.com"
});


module.exports = (app) => {
  const logger = console;

assistant.intent('Sales',(conv, params) => {
 var  pcode = params.myproduct;

// console.log(pcode)

    const token = '3369708919812376';
    const serviceID = '502';
    const P_STATE_CD = 'ALL';
    const P_FO_CD = 'ALL';
    const P_DISTT_CD = 'ALL';
    const P_DATE = '16/12/2019';
    const  P_PRD_GROUP = pcode;
    const P_PERSONAL_NO = '106296';
        var data = {"token" : token,"serviceID" : serviceID,"P_STATE_CD" : P_STATE_CD,"P_FO_CD" : P_FO_CD,"P_DISTT_CD" : P_DISTT_CD,"P_DATE" : P_DATE,"P_PRD_GROUP" : P_PRD_GROUP ,"P_PERSONAL_NO" : P_PERSONAL_NO };
        var sdata = JSON.stringify(data);

                    const options = {
                        method: 'POST',
                        uri: 'http://chatbotWebservice/resources/webservice/service' ,
                        body: JSON.parse(sdata) ,
                        json: true
                    }
        return request(options)
            .then( body => {
                 var unit = body
                unit.intent = "Sales"
                unit.value1 = unit.saleInfo[0].QMTD
                unit.value2 = unit.saleInfo[0].QYTD
                unit.value3 = unit.saleInfo[0].O_UOM
                unit.value4 = null
                unit.value5 = null

                delete unit.saleInfo
                var unit2 = JSON.stringify(unit)
                console.log(unit2)

          conv.ask(unit2);
              })
              .catch( err => {
               console.error( err );
               conv.ask('Something went wrong. What should I do now?');
                 });
  })
```

And the error like this

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at request.then.body (/home/dbalounge/GoogleDF/service.js:40:44)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Please help me out this. Thank You in Advance

Comment: What's line 40. The error is not happening in the code you posted.

Comment: I edited my code please review it.. 40th line is **unit.value1 = unit.saleInfo[0].QMTD** @marcos

Comment: `console.log(body)` and show the output, but the error is clear, `.saleInfo` is undefined.

Comment: **{ error_code: '-1', error_msg: 'here 4:3--null' }
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at request.then.body (/home/dbalounge/GoogleDF/service.js:41:44)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)** @marcos

Comment: **{
    "saleInfo": [
        {
            "QMTD": "460392.615",
            "VMTD": "2538893950",
            "QYTD": "5784069.226",
            "VYTD": "31852760362",
            "O_UOM": "MT"
        }
    ]
}** @MarcosCasagrande

Comment: `console.log(typeof body)` outputs `string` right?

Comment: yes @MarcosCasagrande

Comment: Check my answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `body` is coming as a string, probably because the server is not setting the correct `Content-Type` to the response, and `request` is ignoring `json: true` option. So you should use `JSON.parse` on it, and then access the `saleInfo`

```
return request(options)
   .then( body => {
    var unit = JSON.parse(body)
    unit.intent = "Sales"
    unit.value1 = unit.saleInfo[0].QMTD
    /* ... */
 });
```

Aside from that `body: JSON.parse(sdata)` in your call is not needed, you're stringifying `data` to `sdata` to parse it back again, just use `data` directly:

```
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'http://chatbotWebservice/resources/webservice/service' ,
    body: data,
    json: true
}
```

Comment: after execute the code ...error  coming like this**SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1**  @MarcosCasagrande

Comment: Then `body` is not a string as you mentioned it is.

Comment: sorry its a object @marcos

Comment: Then post the object correctly, because it's not the one you showed. Otherwise you wouldn't be getting that error.

Comment: **{"token" : "3369708919812376","serviceID" : "502","P_STATE_CD" : "ALL","P_FO_CD" : "ALL","P_DISTT_CD" : "ALL","P_DATE" : "16/12/2019","P_PRD_GROUP" : "UREA","P_PERSONAL_NO" : "107077" }** @marcos

Comment: That's not the object you showed before. There's no `saleInfo` property there...So you're trying to access something that doesn't exist.

Comment: with the my code i can access the post api and its also giving me response. but when i put entity param in gives error what i mention in the question. @marcos

Comment: this is reponse coming from api **{"intent":"Sales","value1":"460464.435","value2":"5784141.046","value3":"MT","value4":null,"value5":null}** @marcos

Comment: What does body outputs. If there's no saleInfo property in that response, what are you trying to do. It's not clear at all. You're trying to access a property that does not exist.

Comment: the output is like that only **{ "saleInfo": [ { "QMTD": "460392.615", "VMTD": "2538893950", "QYTD": "5784069.226", "VYTD": "31852760362", "O_UOM": "MT" } ] }** thats why we use **unit.value3 = unit.saleInfo[0].O_UOM** and this output what i sent to you is modified **{"intent":"Sales","value1":"460464.435","value2":"5784141.046","value3":"MT","value4":null,"value5":null}** @marcos

Comment: If `body` contains: `{ "saleInfo": [ { "QMTD": "460392.615", "VMTD": "2538893950", "QYTD": "5784069.226", "VYTD": "31852760362", "O_UOM": "MT" } ] }` As an `Object`, then it's impossible to get that error in the line you showed. Because you can clearly see `saleInfo` there. So, either it's a string, or that's not the output of `body`.

Comment: if the paramter in number comes like **502** if the parater in string comes like** [ 'Urea' ]** from dialogflow to webhook fulfillment. so if i put number than resposing but if i type UREA it goes like **[ 'Urea' ]** and gives error. i checked the log.@marcos

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying being honest. If the API is responding differently depending on what you send to it, you should handle that case, instead of always trying to access `saleInfo`.

Comment: Thank you @marcos for your time......may be i have to rectify all the code once.. if i gt any thing thn i ll let you know here...thanks for alll

Comment: You're welcome. I'll be happy to review it afterwards, since it's not very clear right now, apologies.